# OneToMany failing to save with EntityNotFound

Tags: hibernate, jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find gateway.model.security.Role with id MONITOR
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1257)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1140)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:457)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:551)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:714)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replaceAssociations(TypeHelper.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:419)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:901)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:887)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

here's the standard spring security jdbc table layout

```
create table users
(
    username          text    not null primary key,
    password          text    not null,
    rabbitmq_password text    not null,
    enabled           boolean not null
);
create table authorities
(
    username  text not null references users (username),
    authority text not null,
    unique (username, authority)
);
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
data class User(
    @Id
    val username: String
) {
    lateinit var password: String
    @Column(name = "rabbitmq_password")
    lateinit var rabbitmqPassword: String
    var enabled: Boolean = false

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn( name="username")
    val roles: MutableSet<Role> = mutableSetOf()
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table( name="authorities")
class Role(
    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column( name="authority")
    val name: RoleName
)
```

```
enum class RoleName {
    MONITOR
}
```

```
interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<User, String>
```

this is happening when I call save on the crud repository after creating as folows

```
            val user = User(serialNumber)
            user.password = mpuas.passwordEncoder.encode(password)
            user.rabbitmqPassword = mpuas.sha256.encode(password)
            user.roles.add(Role(RoleName.MONITOR))
repo.save(user)
```

I tried making role name just a string too, and it still didn't want to map.
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because a role isn't a full entity... this will do for now

```
    @ElementCollection
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "authority")
    @CollectionTable(name = "authorities", joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "username")])
    val roles: MutableSet<RoleName> = mutableSetOf()
```